# Yandex.Direct - API in Python

Tags: python, urllib, yandex

I am relatively new to Python, however I am trying to get my head around some mid-high level code which perhaps someone could help explain.

Basically, I am building an API connection to Yandex.Direct (the equivalent of Google Adwords in Russia). Here you can find an API code example: http://api.yandex.com/direct/doc/examples/python-json.xml

The actual code to establish a connection to the server follows (in Python 2.7):

```
import json, urllib2, httplib

#name and path to files with the secret key and certificate 
KEYFILE = '/path/to/private.key'
CERTFILE = '/path/to/cert.crt' 

class YandexCertConnection(httplib.HTTPSConnection):
    def __init__(self, host, port=None, key_file=KEYFILE, cert_file=CERTFILE, timeout=30):
        httplib.HTTPSConnection.__init__(self, host, port, key_file, cert_file)

class YandexCertHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
    def https_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(YandexCertConnection, req) 
    https_request = urllib2.AbstractHTTPHandler.do_request_

urlopener = urllib2.build_opener(*[YandexCertHandler()])

#address for sending JSON requests
url = 'https://api.direct.yandex.ru/json-api/v4/'

#input data structure (dictionary)
data = {
   'method': 'GetClientInfo',
   'param': ['agrom'],
   'locale': 'en'
}

#convert the dictionary to JSON format and change encoding to UTF-8
jdata = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')

#implement the request
response = urlopener.open(url, jdata)

#output results
print response.read().decode('utf8')
```

I don't fully comprehend the following part of this code:

```
class YandexCertConnection(httplib.HTTPSConnection):
    def __init__(self, host, port=None, key_file=KEYFILE, cert_file=CERTFILE, timeout=30):
        httplib.HTTPSConnection.__init__(self, host, port, key_file, cert_file)

class YandexCertHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
    def https_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(YandexCertConnection, req) 
    https_request = urllib2.AbstractHTTPHandler.do_request_

urlopener = urllib2.build_opener(*[YandexCertHandler()])
```

Would appreciate it if someone could answer the following questions:
**1.** How does the code above work step by step? For example how do the different objects interact with each other? A detailed explanation would be great! :)
**2.** What does the * indicate here: `urllib2.build_opener(*[YandexCertHandler()])` **3.** How would one write the code above in Python 3.3 without using classes?

Thank you very much!

Aivoric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2**. `func(*args)` means `func(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...)`, and if `args` is `[x]` then it's just `func(x)`.

In the example it should've been `build_opener(YandexCertHandler())`, I see no reason to complicate the code with [argument list unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

**3**. In Python 3.3 without using classes I would use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module:

```
import json
import requests

# name and path to files with the secret key and certificate
KEYFILE = '/path/to/private.key'
CERTFILE = '/path/to/cert.crt' 

# address for sending JSON requests
url = 'https://api.direct.yandex.ru/json-api/v4/'

# input data structure (dictionary)
data = {
   'method': 'GetClientInfo',
   'param': ['agrom'],
   'locale': 'en'
}

# convert the dictionary to JSON format and change encoding to UTF-8
jdata = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')

response = requests.post(url, data=jdata, cert=(CERTFILE, KEYFILE))

print(response.content)
```

If it works (didn't test it), it also works in Python 2.

Comment: Hi gatto, thanks for the fast reply! Part 2 is clear so thank you! For part 3, did you mean to use the urllib.request library? I went through all the methods available for it but can't find a single one where I can pass a certificate + key file. This is precisely where it gets confusing because I believe somehow one needs to interact with the httplib.HTTPSConnection class in order to establish a secure connection to the remote server using the certificate and key...any thoughts on that? :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, I meant `requests` module, added the link to the answer.

Comment: Also there is no `httplib` in Python 3, see the docs on [http.client](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPSConnection) and on [load_cert_chain](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain).

Comment: Thanks Gatto - my mistake, never used that library before! Going to take a look now :) thank you!